# CSS - скрыть элемент в конце анимации

Tags: css

Как сделать так, чтобы в конце анимации элемент был убран?
Это не работает:

```
    @keyframes move1 {
            0% {height: 0px;}
            100% {height: 100px; display: none;}
    }
    .moving1 { animation: move1 0.30s ease 1 alternate forwards; }
```

Comment: Странная логика. Увеличить объект чтобы его скрыть

Comment: ты лучше весь код выложи, а не огрызок, из которого не ясно ничего. и объясни чего хочешь добиться и что именно не получается...

Comment: Свойство display не анимируется.

Comment: @Air что-то такое хочет :)
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vWmLeM

Comment: websnap, спасибо, я даже не думал о прозрачности, все работает)